# What algorithm decideds whether to retain a word or drop it while downsizing a dictionary?

Tags: dictionaries

One approach I can think of is eliminating most of the words that are very commonly used in spoken English(since a prospective reader is likely to know meaning of most frequently used words, or he/she can get the meaning of those words from his/her peers)

But when I look at pocket dictionaries this does not seem to be the case. How is it actually decided which words to retain and which to drop ?

Comment: Hi, thanks for joining the site! Unfortuantely this question is off topic because it isn't about the English language or its usage. Please read [the tour page](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about ELL.

Comment: This is an interesting and important subject, but is in the domain of lexicography, and not really on-topic here.. You'd have to approach the editorial boards concerned (or check their websites) on an individual basis. I'd just put in that in most modern dictionaries, currency is prioritised: 'Entries are ordered to display the most common meanings that are being used in modern English first, with less common senses further down the entry' ([oxforddictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/words/the-oxford-english-dictionary)). The OED is arranged differently (but has most words).

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the dictionary.

Some are entirely at the discretion of the editors, others are based on popularity and usage.

Some take decisions each year on new words to add and words to remove (again, usage or popularity are the key criteria), whilst the main body of the dictionary remains the same.

Contrary to your assumption though, popular words are **not** dropped. They are the most likely to remain in the dictionary, whilst those almost never used are likely to be left out!